# Python curses TypeError when exiting wrapper

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.5 and when wrapping my `main()` function with `curses.wrapper` I'm getting the following error after my program exits successfully:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
     wrapper(main(SCREEN))
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Some amplifying code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize screen
    SCREEN = curses.initscr()

    # Run program with wrapper in case it fails
    wrapper(main(SCREEN))

    # Terminal cleanup
    curses.nocbreak()
    SCREEN.keypad(False)
    curses.echo()
```

If I use `CTRL + C` to attempt to exit the program while it's running, the exception is shown but the terminal remains in a disarrayed state (wrapper doesn't do it's job). Am I missing an something obvious here?

- EDIT *

I confirmed this also happens on Ubuntu 14.10 server edition over a remote SSH terminal session.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the entire point of `wrapper()` is to avoid all those other curses calls you're making in the example, and in fact, what you're doing is calling `initscr()` twice (first explicitly, then implicitly).

Comment: How would I get the screen without calling `initscr()`? As far as I know `wrapper()` does not provide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're calling the `curses.wrapper` function wrongly.
From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper):

`curses.wrapper(func, ...)` Initialize curses and call another callable object, func, which should be the rest of your curses-using application. (...) The callable object func is then passed the main window ‘stdscr’ as its first argument, followed by any other arguments passed to wrapper().

In your example, it should look like this:

```
def main(SCREEN):
    ... # My program code

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # The function main gets the stdscr passed by curses itself
    wrapper(main)
```

#### If you need to access to stdscr before the main call

I would not use wrapper in that case, but use [curses.endwin()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.html#curses.endwin) to deinitialize the curses library. *Untested* example:

```
SCREEN = curses.initscr()
# Modify your curses settings here

try:
    main(SCREEN)
except: # End curses session before raising the error
    curses.endwin()
    raise
else: # End curses session if program terminates normally
    curses.endwin()
```

Comment: What if I needed access to the screen before I called my `main()` function? Is using `wrapper` in that case not valid?